# Execute CSS Transition at the same time

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions

So, I have a button that has a Font Awesome icon added on the end of it. I am using `:after` on the button to display the icon, which is working great.

I have a CSS transition that eases, but it doesn't work how I expect. I would like both the button text and the `:after` text to ease at the same time. Right now, the button text eases then the `:after` text eases...not one fluid transition. It's like there is a 0.5s delay because of the transition.

Here's my code for the button:

```css
.gform_button {
  background: #363794;
  border: 2px solid #363794;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.gform_button:hover {
  color: #ff9b00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gform_button:after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f135";
  font: var(--fa-font-solid);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.gform_button:hover:after {
  color: #ff9b00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button class="button gform_button" id="gform_submit_button_1">
  <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

I am pretty sure the key is my transition tag, I'm thinking it's because I have transition: `all` because I know that effects each item individually. I've seen this before, so I thought it was a quick fix (initially). I thought if I changed `all` to `color`, I'd be in business, but that still functions the same way - the button text displays then after 0.5s the `:after` displays.

I can't adjust the actual code because the button is being generated by a WordPress site, which is why using `:after` is a great solution most of the time.

Is there a way I could redo things so that both of these (the button text and the `:after`) change color at the same time when they transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't that they're transitioning at different speeds – the text is transitioning colors while the icon *is not*. The icon just changes immediately when hovered.

That's because you've specified color values on the `:after` and `:hover:after`, and it's not transitioned.

The most obvious fix is to also add a transition to it, right?

But, even better: instead, remove the `color` values from the `:after` selector, and just let it inherit the parent's color!

(Also, you are correct that you should stay away from `any` – transitions are very performance expensive on *most* CSS properties, so you should always specify exactly which ones you want)

```css
.gform_button {
  background: #363794;
  border: 2px solid #363794;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.gform_button:hover {
  color: #ff9b00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gform_button:after {
  content: "\f135";
  font: var(--fa-font-solid);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button class="button gform_button" id="gform_submit_button_1">
  <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the feedback and the suggestions! I implemented the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/jpn9z1k0/ - now when I hover both the text and icon hover together!! Yay! However, when i mouse out it seems like it takes longer for the icon to clear it's hover color than the text. I thought initially that may be because of the font size, but it still happens even after I change it 10px. Please see the fiddle :-) Any ideas?

Comment: You're not using my CSS :) you don't need to specify `transition` or `color` at all for the `:after` pseudo element!

Comment: Please make sure to accept my answer if it solved your issue!

Comment: Hey there, sorry about that! I had pasted your code in and thought I had saved the fork! I appreciate all the help and suggestions...this definitely did the trick :-)